# Bundle update for padrino app: could not find compatible versions for "tilt"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, padrino, tilt

Running `bundle update` on my padrino app gives me:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "tilt":
  In Gemfile:
    padrino (= 0.11.1) ruby depends on
      tilt (~> 1.3.0) ruby

    padrino (= 0.11.1) ruby depends on
      tilt (1.4.0)
```

This just started happening: not sure what's changed.
Running Ruby `1.9.3-p392`

`Gemfile` looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'unicorn'
gem 'rake'

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'slim'
gem 'mongoid', '~>3.0.0'

gem 'haml'

gem 'padrino', '0.11.1'
```

Comment: have you tried including tilt in the gem file? It's not necessarily included in Padrino

Comment: Thanks @baordog: it doesn't make a difference, and `tilt` is included as a dependency in Padrino

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `gem 'tilt', '1.3.7'` to your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Thanks, this workaround makes it resolve (as per @magnus-holm's explanation)

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in the resolver of Bundler. I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/2464

For now you can fix it by forcing Tilt to the 1.3-branch:

```
# Force Tilt 1.3 to avoid resolver bug: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/2464
gem 'tilt', '~> 1.3.0'
```

Comment: Thanks @magnus-holm ... also for explanation. It works with an initial ```bundle install``` but on running ```bundle update```, I get the error again. I don't get the error if I use @ujifgc's answer below.